# To delete everything between square brackets

Tags: linux, sed

I need to find the line in a `lvm.conf` file which starts with string, `global_filter` and remove everything between the square brackets except `"r/.*/"`.

There is only 1 line which starts with global_filter.

Before Removal:

```
global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sda.*$|", "a|^/dev/sdb.*$|", "r/.*/"]
```

After the Removal, it should be -

```
global_filter = [, "r/.*/"]
```

Comment: Okay, I suppose you know how to address a line in `sed` and you know the `s` command, so the only problem is to define a good regex for your match? How about `[.*,`? Now build your command or ask a specific question.

Comment: Should `global_filter` lines that  do _not_ contain `"r/.*/"` be modified?

Comment: Are you sure you want to leave the leading comma in?

Comment: Yes I want the comma should be retained. And also only that line in the file should be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/^global_filter/{\|"r/\.\*/"|s|.*|global_filter = [, "r/.*/"]|;}' data
```

## Explanation

```
sed -i -e '
   # look at only lines that begin with global_filter
   /^global_filter/{
      # and also they should contain the string "r/.*/"
      # change everything to the following expression
      \|"r/\.\*/"| s|.*|global_filter = [, "r/.*/"]|

      ## alternatively could be written:
      #\|"r/\.\*/"|c\
#global_filter = [, "r/.*/"]
   }
' data
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
This replaces the entire file. I want only that line to be modified.

Comment: I modified the command by replacing the -n flag by -i and it worked.
It is working as expected but I am seeing a duplicate entry the next line.

Comment: Can you please help me in that.

Comment: Yes I tried with the first method itself. It is giving duplicate entry in the file.

Comment: With -n option, the entire file is being replaced by just the global_filter line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ echo 'global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sda.$|", "a|^/dev/sdb.$|", "r/.*/"]'|\
sed -E 's/(^global_filter = \[)(.*)(, "r.*$)/\1\3/'
```

Output:

```
global_filter = [, "r/.*/"]
```

Comment: Just try on the input: `global_filter = [ "a|^/dev/sda.$|", "a|^/dev/sdb.$|", "r/Dot_Star/"]'`

Comment: Sorry John this is not working

Comment: I mean for file input, I could not get this working.. can you help me out.

Comment: @user7290726 I see. Could you please than post an excerpt of your input file to make it easier to guess what you want?

Comment: The file has only 1 line which starts with global_filter. And I need the changes as said earlier.